# VBA: "Automation Error. Exception occurred." when using UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

My code copies data from different workbooks into other workbooks. It loops through 12 workbooks into which data is copied, and each of those 12 workbooks opens (and closes) 6 files from which it gets the data.

The first step is that I show the user a UserForm, where they can select a year and a quarter. The code itself works when:

1. I leave out the Userform and enter the date (= the variables `qVar`, `yVar` and `fullDate`) directly inside the code.
2. I leave in the Userform, but reduce the number of workbooks from 12 to maybe 7 or so.

If I use the UserForm with all 12 workbooks, I get the

> "Automation Error. Exception Occurred."

and Excel shuts down. The UserForm in question consists of a combobox, a frame on which there are 4 option buttons and two command buttons.

Code for the UserForm (`qVar`, `yVar` and `fullDate` are global variables):

```
Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub cmdOk_Click()
    Dim QuartalStr As String
    Dim oControl As Control

    If cboJahr.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Select year"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each oControl In frmQuartalsauswahl.fraQuartale.Controls
        If oControl.Value = True Then
            qVar = oControl.Caption
        End If
    Next oControl

    yVar = CStr(cboJahr.Value)

    Select Case qVar
        Case "Q1"
            fullDate = yVar & ".03.31"
        Case "Q2"
            fullDate = yVar & ".06.30"
        Case "Q3"
            fullDate = yVar & ".09.30"
        Case "Q4"
            fullDate = yVar & ".12.31"
    End Select

Unload Me
Call QuarterlyReport.WithUserForm
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim yearsArray() As Integer
    Dim startyear As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    startyear = 2017
    i = 0

    Do While startyear <= Year(Date)
        ReDim Preserve yearsArray(i)
        yearsArray(i) = startyear
        startyear = startyear + 1
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    cboJahr.List = yearsArray  
End Sub
```

Does anyone have an idea what I should do or what I should look for?

**edit:** Ok, now I got a new error: Excel crashes with the classic error message: ["Microsoft Excel has stopped working"](https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/768a07fd-eafc-4610-b072-3a9fc4cd799d). One time Excel restored the updated workbooks, which told me:  That time it occured for the 10th of the 12 workbooks, after the data from 5 of the 6 source files has been copied. However, that's the same code as for the other workbooks. Anyway, ever since Excel doesn't restore anything but the original files - either that's an issue with Excel or it means my code crashes without altering the files. Without the userform the code still works without any issues.

Comment: In which code line does the error occur?

Comment: Debug your code. Go through it step by step (using F8) and check wich line of code causes the issue. • If you say *"Excel shuts down"* does that mean Excel force closes (crashes) and is not open anymore? If that happens please make sure you are on the latest version of Excel (run an update).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I went through it twice with F8 (it takes quite a long time) and no error occurred. However, after that for some reason I didn't get the automation error anymore, but "MS Excel has stopped working" (see my edit). 

That also means I can't tell you where the problem occurs. However, using F8 showed me Excel slows down significantly, I'm guessing because I leave the 12 workbooks open. I have my reasons for that, but once I have  the time I will find another way for this. I don't know why this would help with my problem, but I'll try it anyway.

Comment: @help-info.de Please see my response to Pᴇʜ and my edit in the post.

Comment: @Alex Actually this looks like Excel is running out of memory (there are cases where Excel just crashes if it runs out of memory). Depending on how much data is in your 12 workbooks it can be that if Excel runs out of memory (it is limited to 2 GB for each instance). Is it really needed that you have the 12 workbooks open at the **same** time? Or can you open/edit/close each file after another so only one file is open at a time. • Another posibility to overcome the 2 GB limit is to open each file in a new Excel instance.

Comment: @Alex also refer to [Memory usage in the 32-bit edition of Excel 2013 and 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3066990/memory-usage-in-the-32-bit-edition-of-excel-2013-and-2016)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I left them open because if an error has occurred (like a workbook hasn't been found), I want the user to have the option to decide whether they want to save the partially updated workbooks or to close them without saving. The intention is to not render the whole macro useless just because one file out of 12*6= 72 is missing. 

My first thought now is to save the filenames of the backups I create to an array. If the user wants to undo the changes, I'll let the code overwrite the updated workbooks with the backups.

Comment: well, checking if all assumed files exist **before** you start calculating might be an option ;) Then you can cancel and note the user before you start calculating at all. Data validation (especially before running a long job) should be mandatory.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yeah, that makes a lot of sense. Initially I did it my way because I wanted to let the user look at the partially updated workbooks and then decide, but so far I haven't found the time to read up on how to do this (= not just hide the userform, but let the user still interact with Excel despite the UF being up) and I think it's just something that's nice to have, but not necessary.